# python bs4 find() return none

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-mining

I am getting none by using bs4 find() function even it is exists in the html. I am trying to get all **div** with a class **tab_content**.I am finding this on this link https://sofad.qc.ca/index.php?id_product=464&controller=product&id_lang=1. So kindly suggest me how to do this in a right way.
**This is the code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'https://sofad.qc.ca/index.php?id_category=78&controller=category&id_lang=1'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
tb = soup.find_all('a', class_='product_img_link')


for item in tb:
    link = item.get('href')
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    try:
        title = soup.find('h1', {'itemprop':'name'}).text
    except:
        title = ''
    try:
        price = soup.find('span', id='our_price_display').text
    except:
        price = ''
    try:
        img = soup.find('img', id='bigpic').get('src')
    except:
        img = ''
    try:
        dv = " ".join(soup.find('div', class_='rte').text.split())
    except:
        dv = ''
    for dvv in soup.find_all('div', class_='tab_content'):
        print(dvv)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the syntax is `findAll` NOT `find_all`!

To find a `div` with a class of `tab_content`:

```
tab_content = soup.findAll('div', class_='tab_content')
```

**FYI, there is no div with tab_content class in the html tree on that page.**